# lost genuine version of my PC with out restore

Tags: system-installation

I bought My laptop with genuine Ubuntu but lost and installed other 
operating system can i get the genuine version to download.

Comment: You can download Ubuntu from Ubuntu.com

Answer (score 2):

I also have a "Ubuntu Certified" laptop (Dell Lattitude E7440), which came with pre-installed Ubuntu. I found out that the "factory" operative system is just a "dd" of the image into the HD of the laptop, and that image is basically the same you can get from the Ubuntu repositories. It might come with some special driver, but nothing you can't easily install yourself after installing the normal Ubuntu (or *ubuntu).

I would actually recommend you an Ubuntu certified laptop because the hardware should be fully supported, but otherwise, just reinstall a fresh an updated *ubuntu on it and it will be even better than the factory one.